# Separate shipping method - rates for each store at checkout

Tags: magento2, multistore, shipping-methods

What i want to achieve is the following.
I'll be having a multi-store or multi-website Magento. Haven't decided yet.
There's going to be one single front for all those stores-websites.

During checkout i want the user to pay shipping rates based on the stores he has purchased items from. Meaning.

```
He buys 1 item from store A
He buys 2 items from store B.
```

At checkout ( he'll only do 1 payment btw ) there's going to be two extra shipping rates applied to his order.
One from store A for the 1 item, and one from store B for the 2 item. He'll also be able to pick different shipping methods between stores.

Is this something ( at least on some point ) achievable on Magento CE 2 ?

I know i'll probably have to write some code for it but giving me a few hints ( like using something like multishipping ) will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up rewriting the `Multishipping` module that Magento has and implementing a custom solution on there.

If anyone ever faces a similar issue please do contact me for more information

Comment: Can you please share the code where you have customized the shipping methods for displaying separately for each store in M2

Comment: Sorry was on vacation. Ended up using the WebMatrix and modified that to my needs. Please send me a message for what you are trying to achieve and i'll be glad to help you - share my code.

Comment: Its a multistore setup with cart sharing, so if in a cart there are products from two stores then the customer should be able to select different shipping methods for each store.

Comment: i basically rewrote the `multiship` magento 2 extension to match that and my needs but for websites and not stores. send me an email i can share the code if you like but you'll probably have to make some adjustments yourself.

Comment: @LefterisL I would be very keen to see this module you wrote we might just need to do this on our next product can you share on github maybe?

Comment: Hello, Can we also change the shipping method name for store wise as magento 2 by default is using shipping and payment method name As global but yeah we can change the title but That didn't helped So I need to change the functionality to Make Shipping and Payment method store wise, But It's a mess If You can help me in this that should be very helpful